# Is it possible to send data to qemu's parallelport?

Tags: virtualization, qemu, emulation

I'm testing qemu's parallelport and tried to send data to it. With a connected chardevice I'm not able to change the state of the registers.
With parport forwarding I'm not able to access my virtualparport(linux-host) and send (same time like qemu) data to it, because qemu claimed the port and won't release it until the proccess stops.
Is there maybe a way to split a host parport device in a way that two proccesses can communicate over those devices?
Or can somebody confirm that there is no way to send data to qemu's parport?
I can confirm that a printer device on the guest is waiting for inputs from the parport when parport forwarding was turned on in qemu - but how to write on it without a real device?